# Want to implement SimpleTree in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, tree, relation, octobercms

I want to implement parent child relationship in OctoberCMS. I have two model client and session. this is one to many relationship. One client have multiple session. My target is when clicking on a row of client list it will expand the session child row. Here is code of my models -

### Client Model

```
<?php 
namespace Smriad\Pracitioner\Models;

use Model;


class Client extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\SimpleTree;


    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'smriad_pracitioner_client';

    public $hasMany = [
        'session' => ['Smriad\Pracitioner\Models\Session', 'key' => 'client_id']
        // ^ you can use house instead houses for relation name
    ];
}
```

### Session Model

```
<?php namespace Smriad\Pracitioner\Models;

use Model;

/**
 * Model
 */
class Session extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\SimpleTree;
    /*
     * Disable timestamps by default.
     * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'smriad_pracitioner_client_session';

    public $belongsTo = [
        'client' => ['Smriad\Pracitioner\Models\Client', 'key' => 'client_id']
        // ^ you can use house instead houses for relation name
    ];
}
```

Comment: you need to add a parent_id column in db table.
see here for more information.
https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#simple-tree

Comment: i have client_id in both table

Comment: Sorry but you need some custom solution as `SimpleTree` could work for only for `same table parent-child relation` here you see `two different models/tables`, so i guess up to my knowledge OctoberCMS do not support it out of the box.